# how evaluate Firstordefault Linq in Ms Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, the table contains:

```
Code  order  jobseqno  LongDesc
123   1234   1         ToothPaste
123   1234   1         ToothPAste 123
123   1234   1         ToothPAste 125
123   1234   1         ToothPAste 126
124   1234   1         ToothBrush 120
124   1234   1         ToothBrush 129
124   1234   1         ToothBrush 156
```

The result must be:

```
Code  order  jobseqno  LongDesc
123   1234   1         ToothPaste
124   1234   1         ToothBrush 120
```

How can I do that? The `Code` column is important; if I catch First Code 123, ToothPaste is enough, I don't need 123 125 126 version. I need a function not `Top()` not `max()`?  I need second table I need only which has first code(barcode) I must add second table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation of what you need is a bit confusing, but based on your desired result:

```
SELECT Code, Order, jobseqno, MIN(LongDesc)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Code, Order, jobseqno
```

Comment: +1 to your answer to an obscure question with unclear requirements. This answer of course is assuming that he wants to group by order and jobseqno, which he might want to, but again we will never know, will we?